# How do I color a region under a distribution curve in R

Tags: r

Let's start with say:

```
x <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
y <- dbeta(x, 2, 5)
plot(x, y, type = "l")
```

Now suppose I want to color the region between 0.5 and 4.5 as shown below:

[image]

**How do I do it?**

I hacked it by the following line

```
sapply(seq(0.05, 0.35, 0.01), function(x) lines(c(x, x), c(0, dbeta(x, 2, 5)), col = "yellow", lwd = 4))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with `ggplot2::stat_function`, which is similar to `curve`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x = 0:1), aes(x)) + 
    stat_function(fun = dbeta, args = c(2, 5), geom = 'area', 
                  xlim = c(0.05, 0.35), fill = 'yellow') + 
    stat_function(fun = dbeta, args = c(2, 5))
```

[image]

If you'd rather preprocess the data like in your original approach instead of letting ggplot interpolate for you, you could use the more ordinary `geom_area` and `geom_line` to produce the same plot.

Answer (score 3):

Since you started with `plot`,  a base R solution would be:

```
x <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
y <- dbeta(x, 2, 5)
plot(x, y, type = "l")

x2 <- seq(0.05,0.35,0.01)
y2 <-  dbeta(x2, 2, 5)
x2 = c(0.05,x2,0.35)
y2 = c(0,y2,0)
polygon(x2,y2, col="yellow", border=NA)
```

[image: Area under curve]

Comment: If you plot the line after the polygon, e.g. initialize with `plot(x, y, type = 'n')`, plot the polygon, and then `curve(dbeta(x, 2, 5), add = TRUE)`, you can keep the line crisp.